# Python3 wrong import path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a tree that looks like this:

```
└──env
│
└──Project
    │
    ├── DirA
    │   ├── A_MAIN
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── FILES
    │           └── __init__.py
    │           └── fileA1
    │           └── fileA2
    │
    ├── FoldersB
    │   └── DirB
    │       ├── A_MAIN
    │           ├── __init__.py
    │           ├── FILES
    │               └── __init__.py
    │               └── fileA1
    │               └── fileA2
    ├── Tests
    │   └── test.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    │
    ├── __init__.py
```

In (both) fileA1 I have something similar to:

```
from A_MAIN.FILES.fileA2 import <CLASS>
```

For whatever reason however, the top fileA1 is importing the  implementation from FoldersB/../../../fileA2, instead of the fileA2 in its same directory.

It may be important to note that all the folder names, class names, etc are the same. My hunch is something is going wrong in the sys.path, but I'm having trouble debugging it.

```
sys.path:
[
'/Users/Shared/FolderX/FolderY/Project/Tests',
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', 
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
'/Users/Shared/FolderX/FolderY/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
'/Users/Shared/FolderX/FolderY/Project/FoldersB/DirB',
'/Users/Shared/FolderX/FolderY',
'/Users/Shared/FolderX/FolderY/Project/DirA/A_MAIN/irrelevant_package'
]
```

From inside DirA.../fileA1:

```
import A_MAIN.FILES.fileA2 as testImportPath

print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# Results in: 
# /Users/Shared/FolderX/FolderY/Project/DirA/A_MAIN/FILES/fileA1

print(os.path.abspath(testImportPath.__file__))
# Results in:
# /Users/Shared/FolderX/FolderY/Project/FoldersB/DirB/A_MAIN/FILES/fileA2
```

I want to be able to compare the implementations of CLASS in both fileA1's (who contain fileA2's CLASS as member variables) from the Project directory, which is why I'm running into this strange environment.

The current working directory is `/Tests/test.py`.

EDIT: Updated tree to be more correct and included sys paths and os path information

Comment: Is your current working directory `FoldersB` when you run the script?

Comment: The working directory is in a file within Project (top layer, siblings to `FolderB` and `A`)

Comment: Sorry* within a file within a folder on the same level as `FolderB`, i.e. `Project/Directory/$CWD.py`

Comment: Please put that into your question. Also, if you want us to debug your `sys.path`, please print it out and put that in the question, too.

Comment: @abarnert updated!

Comment: OK, how did you get `'/Users/Shared/FolderX/FolderY/Project/FoldersB/DirB'` into your `sys.path`? That shouldn't be there.

Comment: Frankly I'm not sure, I've been scouring wear it could have happened but I can't find it. Even if I remove it, it keeps getting re-added. If it's relevant, I've needed to import FileA1/2 via path so I've been using importlib and importing them from spec.

Comment: Well, whatever's causing that is almost surely what's causing all your problems, so that's what you need to track down. Can you grep for `sys.path` anywhere in your code to see if there's something obvious?

Comment: sys.path didn't turn up any active code in my project, I have a feeling it may be because of the way python3 env is installing sub-directories, sys.path is called inside the env dir - it might be automatically caching sub packages it's finding. Removing the paths also prevents me from important the files from the sub packages.